# Using selenium to open multiple articles with the same class and scrape data from them

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, dataset, chatbot

I am trying to create a dataset for my chatbot to learn from by using selenium to scrape data from a website. But the articles I am trying to open have the same class so I have to figure out how to cycle through all of them.

I was able to figure out how to open the first link and scrape the data but I dont know how to click the second and after that third etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import requests
import bs4


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.hybrid.cz/tagy/tesla")

link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nodeTitle")
link.click()
url = driver.current_url
print(url)
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
#print(r.text)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for paragraphs in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"node"}):
    ##print(paragraphs)
    with open('test.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        #print(paragraphs)
        file.write(str(paragraphs))
time.sleep(5)
driver.back()
link2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='nodeTitle']")
print(link2)
#link2.click()
```

And right now I am just trying to get the link to print so I know theres something to click but I have not been able to do that. I would be grateful for any help.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `h2 a` to grab all links to articles from the page. You can store these links to a list and then use this list to grab the articles. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def read_article(url):
    rv = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    for paragraph in soup.find_all("div", {"class":"node"}):
        rv.append(paragraph.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
    return rv

url = 'https://www.hybrid.cz/tagy/tesla'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# 1. read all urls:
all_urls = []
for link in soup.select('h2 a'):
    print(link.text)
    print('https://www.hybrid.cz' + link['href'])
    print('-' * 80)

    all_urls.append('https://www.hybrid.cz' + link['href'])

# 2. print all articles from grabbed urls:
for url in all_urls:
    print(read_article(url))
```

Prints:

```
Tesla opět zdražuje, má k tomu ale pádný důvod: robotické řízení je už v betatestu neuvěřitelné!
https://www.hybrid.cz/tesla-opet-zdrazuje-ma-k-tomu-ale-padny-duvod-roboticke-rizeni-je-uz-v-betatestu-neuveritelne
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tesla zveřejnila finanční výsledky a vytřela analytikům zrak, navýšila příjmy i zisk
https://www.hybrid.cz/tesla-financni-vysledky-vytrela-analytikum-zrak-navysila-prijmy-i-zisk
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tesla rozjíždí betatest robotického řízení, nástup bude extrémně opatrný
https://www.hybrid.cz/tesla-rozjizdi-betatest-robotickeho-rizeni-nastup-bude-exteremne-opatrny
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nové Tesla baterie jsou ještě lepší, než se čekalo: životnost přes 3,5 mil. km!
https://www.hybrid.cz/nove-tesla-baterie-jsou-jeste-lepsi-nez-se-cekalo-zivotnost-pres-35-mil-km
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks, thats was super helpful. You are a lifesaver!